# How to implement IF statement using GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on my first web project and I need help adding IF logic when using GridView. I have a page (CustomerListPage) that has a GridView item that displays a list of customers(rows) that can be clicked. Once the customer is clicked, the user is redirected to a page called "CustomerUsagePage" which shows the most recent record of this customer. This is what my GridView code looks like for my CustomerListPage:

```
 if (GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex == 0)
   {
       //string selectedUser = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString();
       Response.Redirect("CustomerUsagePage.aspx?Customer_Name=" );
       BindGridview();
   }
```

The code for my CustomerUsagePage looks like this:

```
private void BindControlvalues()
{

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.CustomerTable", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    con.Close();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Label4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    Label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    Label2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
    Label3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
}
```

My problem is that I can only add IF logic the page where my GridView is located. I would like to click on a customer and have his data appear on my CustomerUsagePage with an if statement. Is it possible? I know I can do this by adding a page per customer but I dont want to go down that route, it seems to tedious. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "add IF logic"? What are you trying to check?

Comment: I want to check which customer has been selected by checking the index of the rows. Ex: if row[1] {//Display info}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GridView-FormView (Master/Detail) Control`

Link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16780/GridView-FormView-Master-Detail-Control.

Or you can use classic behavior with `ItemCommand` event

```
void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Add")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

      GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];

      .....//Adjust your Response
    }
}
```

Comment: would this code go on the CustomerUsagePage? As is, it seems like it would go in the CustomerListPage where the GridView is.

Comment: I may be wrong, but this does not seem to be where I'm stuck. I already have if statements on my GridView item. The problem is, I am redirecting to the same page (CustomerUsagePage). I think this is the page where the IF statements should go. This way, the page checks which row has been selected to then know which data to display.